# How to add an image from url to temp?

Tags: php

I am using the SimpleImage.php class from: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/ , to resize, compress and save the images.

Usually using it with an image from input:

```
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = 'something.jpg'; 

include('SimpleImage.php');
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($tmp_dir);

$image->resizeToWidth($width);
$image->save('imgd/l'.$file_name);
```

**But how can I deal just with the image url?** (from another website)

```
$img = file_get_contents($url);
```

The above `$img` variable keeps the actual image.
So how can I save it to temp to use it?
If this is the right way.

If it's possible not to have to change SimpleImage.php class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [tempnam()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

> Creates a file with a unique filename, with access permission set to
>   0600, in the specified directory. If the directory does not exist,
>   tempnam() may generate a file in the system's temporary directory, and
>   return the name of that.

```
<?php 
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "UL_IMAGE");
$img = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($tmpfname, $img);

include('SimpleImage.php');
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($tmpfname);

$image->resizeToWidth($width);
$image->save('imgd/l'.$file_name);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks and now I figured out that it works also just with the url, I had another error.